# React Native and Facebook SDK on Android

Tags: react-native, facebook-login

I can't seem to get React Native FBSDK work on Android. I completed all the steps from registering the app to configuring the manifest file (can be found on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-android-current)

When I run the app I get the error: **The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.** I am using the latest version of **react-native-fbsdk** so the method above is deprecated. Also if I put the call into the main application class, the app crashes on startup.

So I'm kind of stuck here. Everything runs smooth on iOS but Android gives me headaches.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't shown code it's hard to know, but make sure you have:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
  // If you want to use AppEventsLogger to log events:
  AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
  SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
}
```

in your MainApplication class (MainApplication.java)--at least, I didn't see that mentioned in the link you provided. Good luck

Comment: It's not mentioned because it's deprecated :-) With the latest version if you add it, the app crashes.

Comment: Hmm...strange. It's still in the react-native-fbsdk documentation, and it's in a project I just did a few weeks ago that works - although, the docs a bit further down do say you can skip 'the step of calling FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize'. Have you added your app id string to your strings.xml?

Comment: I also put the onActivityResult block (step 7 in your link) in MainActivity.java, not MainApplication.java - and that worked. I'm going to be repeating the process on a new app today, I'll let you know if I have any insights...or, maybe I'll be in trouble too, now!

Comment: I'm seeing that I used: compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.21.1' in my build.gradle dependencies, which may explain the difference.

Comment: Yep, not that I'm suggesting it as a solution, but I can verify that it works using 4.21.1 and the current react-native-fbsdk install instructions...just got it to build in my new app.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue and I realize that I have to complete all steps to configure the native facebook sdk for android. Its mean you need to have a facebook account for this work.
What you need to do next is:

1. In your project open `yourapp/android/build.gradle`
2. Add the Maven Central Repository to build.gradle before dependencies:

   `repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }`
3. Add `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'`to your `build.gradle` dependencies
4. Build project
5. Open your strings.xml file, for example: `/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml.`and add `<string name="facebook_app_id">xxxxxxxxx</string>`
6. Open your AndroidManifest.xml and add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
7. Add meta to application element `<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>`
8. Generate a development key hash

You can see detail in quick start of developer facebook page (developers.facebook.com/quickstarts)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20631752)

Comment: If you build successfully, then feedback to me.